# lucene - cant understand solr behavior (it returns different results if i change places of words in query)

Tags: solr, lucene

i need to select all records which have words "6" and "buldings". i'm creating such query to my solr:

```
/select?q=name:2+AND+buildings
```

solr returns me 128 results. most of results have something like "126 buildings" or "buildings 7260" but i need only records with words "6" and "buildings".

but if i change words places in the query:

```
/select?q=name:buildings+AND+2
```

it returns me absolutely another result - the right one! this time there are no strange records with words "7260" or "126" only records that i really need with words "6" and "buildings".

so please can sombody explain to me why solr returns such a strange result in the first case because i create queries without considering that solr can return different results if words places are changed. and **how can i point solr to search only "6" if it goes before word**?

any help appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name:buildings AND 2` is not the same as `name:2 AND buildings` because the field ("name") is only being applied to the first term in the query.  The other is being searched in the default field for the query parser.

- `name:buildings AND 2` is identical to: `name:buildings AND defaultfield:2`
- `name:2 AND buildings` is identical to: `name:2 AND defaultfield:buildings`

If you want both to be searched in the "name" field, you could use a query like:

```
name:(2 AND buildings)
```